# completing the square to find vertex

Tags: geometry

I have tried figuring it out and I keep getting $(-5,3)$ but it's wrong. can anyone help figure this out?

> Complete the square and find the vertex of the parabola: $y^2+6y+8x+1=0$

Comment: Hint: $y^2+6y+8x+1=0 \rightarrow (y+3)^2 = -8(x-1)$

Comment: Is this exam question? It looks as though you have to enter the answer in the box below.

Answer (score 1):

$$y^2+6y+8x+1=0 → (y+3)^2-9+8x+1=0 → x=\frac{-(y+3)^2+8}{8}$$

So we find the vertex when $y=-3$ and then it is $(x,y)=(1,-3)$